# MS Word VBA. Getting Source object from Footnote field

Tags: vba, ms-word

In my document I must add footnotes to every formula i used. For example, I have some text with added Bibliography source

```
(something like  "some very smart text [WrittenBySb]")
```

and I have formula

```
(for examle : E = mc2)
```

And after that formula I must add footnote contains source. I decided to write a macro that add footnote to formula with selected bibliography source:

```
Sub addFootnoteFromSelection()
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell 'my formula is in table - first row 
                                 'is null. second is actual formula and 
                                 'third contains actual formula's number 
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
With Selection                   'i want footnote mark to be in current 
                                 'formula's number
   With .FootnoteOptions
        .Location = wdBottomOfPage
        .NumberingRule = wdRestartContinuous
        .StartingNumber = 1
        .NumberStyle = wdNoteNumberStyleArabic
   End With
 .Footnotes.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Reference:=""
End With
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Numer wzoru")
Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphJustify
End Sub
```

And that works, but I want to have full source name (like in bibliography field), not a citation mark.
I write a function in vba that returns proper looking and formatted string from Source field:

```
Function stringFromSource(curField As Source) As String
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xmlDoc.LoadXML curField.XML
authors = "":  title = "": publish = "": city = "": year = "": periodic = 
""
'authors
Set surname = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("b:Last")
Set name = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("b:First")
Dim l As Integer
l = 0
For Each el In surname
    If el.Text = "" Then Exit For
    authors = authors + (el.Text & " " & name(l).Text & "  ")
    l = l + 1
Next el
'title
Set titlex = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("b:Title")
For Each el In titlex
    If el.Text = "" Then Exit For
    title = title + (el.Text & " ")
Next el
'publisher
Set pubx = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("b:Publisher")
For Each el In pubx
    publish = publish + (el.Text & " ")
Next el
'city
Set cityx = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("b:City")
If cityx.Length = 0 Then city = city + ("(brak miasta)" & " ")
For Each el In cityx
    city = city + (el.Text & " ")
Next el
'year
Set yearx = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("b:Year")
If yearx.Length = 0 Then year = year + ("(brak roku wydania)" & " ")
For Each el In yearx
    year = year + (el.Text & " ")
Next el
'periodical title
Set periodx = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("b:PeriodicalTitle")
For Each el In period
    periodic = periodic + (el.Text & " ")
Next el

Dim outputString As String
outputString = author & "- " & title & ", " & publish & periodic & ", " & 
year
stringFromSource = outputString
End Function
```

This function works as expected. But I want to loop through all footnotes and convert it to string using my function:

```
Sub convertAllFootnotes()
Dim ftn As Footnote
Dim oRng As Range
 For Each ftn In ActiveDocument.Footnotes
    Set oRng = Selection.Range
    oRng.Start = oRng.Start - 1
    oRng.End = oRng.End + 1
    oRng.Select
    oRng.Text = stringFromSource(ftn) 'i don't know how to get source object 
                                      'from footnote
 Next ftn
End Sub
```

And that is my problem. I don't know how to get Source object from footnote (that has Source object in it, this is not a static string but copied proper Source field)

Comment: What do you mean by `Source Object`?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/source-object-word

Comment: No one has an answer?

Comment: Simply speaking your problem is a bit difficult to reproduce. I think that is the reason you don't get the answer.

Comment: So, maybe somebody can tell me how to  retrieve "Source object" from "Footnote object? That's my main question and issue.

Comment: And to clarify. I want to extract "Source object" from Citation that is in footnote.